# Getting Unmarshall exception while putting data in dynamo db table in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to integrate dynamo db to my spring boot application I have been following this [link][1] to implement the dynamo db into my spring boot application ever time I try to put into my table I get this error "**Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided**".I have created my dynamo db table manually by using aws console
I have mentioned my code below

Controller

```
    @RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostMapping("/emp")
    public String data(Employee employee){
        return employeeRepository.updateData(employee);
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class EmployeeRepository {
    public String updateData(Employee employee) {

        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();

        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("employee");

        Item item = new Item()
                .withPrimaryKey("employeeId", "1")
                .withString("firstName", "micky")
                .withString("lastName", "mouse")
                .withString("emailId", "mic@gmail.com");
         table.putItem(item);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

DynamoDB config

```
@Configuration
public class DynamoDBConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper(){
        return new DynamoDBMapper(buildAmazonDynamoDb());
    }

    private AmazonDynamoDB buildAmazonDynamoDb() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("dyno-config")
                )
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                        "accessKey","SecretKey"))).build();
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="employee")
public class Employee {
    public String employeeId;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String emailId;
}
```

The values mentioned in employee entity are of same name as of mu dynamoDB entity.Can anyone help me out what is wrong with my code
[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html

Answer (score 2):

You are using old V1 code. That is not best practice. Look at this section in the same guide that uses **DynamoDbClient**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/example_cross_DynamoDBDataTracker_section.html

This link uses the **AWS SDK for Java V2** and shows you how to successfully develop a Spring REST API that queries Amazon DynamoDB data.